# jQuery focus on input text with name same as div id

Tags: jquery

I have several links. When I click a link I want jQuery to give focus to the corresponding input.

**Links:**

```
<a href="#" class="copy_go_to_input_field" data-divid="inp_copy_input_item_evidece_38">Focus</a>
<a href="#" class="copy_go_to_input_field" data-divid="inp_copy_input_item_evidece_39">Focus</a>
<a href="#" class="copy_go_to_input_field" data-divid="inp_copy_input_item_evidece_34">Focus</a>
```

**Input fields:**

```
<input type="text" name="inp_copy_input_item_evidece_38" value="2020_71_206_1" size="25" />
<input type="text" name="inp_copy_input_item_evidece_39" value="2020_71_206_1" size="25" />
<input type="text" name="inp_copy_input_item_evidece_40" value="2020_71_206_1" size="25" />
```

jQuery (not working):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.copy_go_to_input_field').click(function() {
        var field = $(this).data('divid');
                $('[name=""+ field + ""]').focus();

        return false;
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `<label>` elements? This is exactly the functionality they were designed for...

Comment: How can i Use the label element?

Comment: Assign your `<input>` an ID, and use the `for` attribute.

Comment: you have a wrong quote positioning, it should be `'[name="'+ field + '"]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that pops up is that it seems you misused the quotes in the name selector.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.copy_go_to_input_field').on('click', function() {
        var field = $(this).data('divid');
        $('[name="'+ field + '"]').focus();

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Also, you should try to use `.on('click', function(){})` instead of the `.click(function(){})`. You can see why here: [Difference between .on('click') vs .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)

You can check the solution posted by @BenM which is much cleaner than mine. The one I posted provides a fix for your JS. But for the functionality you need it's much cleaner to use what @BenM did.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need JS for that. You can do this quite easily using `<label>`. Just assign an ID to your inputs, and use the `for` attribute as follows:

```html
<label class="copy_go_to_input_field" for="inp_copy_input_item_evidece_38">Focus</label>
<label class="copy_go_to_input_field" for="inp_copy_input_item_evidece_39">Focus</label>
<label class="copy_go_to_input_field" for="inp_copy_input_item_evidece_40">Focus</label>

<input type="text" id="inp_copy_input_item_evidece_38" name="inp_copy_input_item_evidece_38" value="2020_71_206_1" size="25" />
<input type="text" id="inp_copy_input_item_evidece_39" name="inp_copy_input_item_evidece_39" value="2020_71_206_1" size="25" />
<input type="text" id="inp_copy_input_item_evidece_40" name="inp_copy_input_item_evidece_40" value="2020_71_206_1" size="25" />
```

Comment: Thanks, this also worked, however I want to do extra things inside my jquery function after giving focus. I will keep this in mind for future problems where I can use labels and inputs.

Comment: "*after giving focus*" - in which case, you should use `$("input").on("focus"...` as they can get focus other ways than clicking the *label*